# Is it possible to exclude all theorems of a type from compilation with a single command?

Tags: theorems, mdframed

I have a theorem type called `application`. It is used to list applications of concepts being discussed in a book. I want to exclude them from a compilation in order to generate a preliminary book that will be tested with some students. The applications and other theorem environments are being saved as a secret for future publication of the complete book.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{applicationSty}{linewidth=1pt, innermargin =1cm, outermargin =1cm}
\newcounter{applicationCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{applicationCounter}{chapter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=applicationSty]{application}[applicationCounter]{Aplication}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\begin{application}
    This is an application.
\end{application}

This is more text.

\begin{application}
    This is another application.
\end{application}

This is more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `comment` package and mark the `application` environment as a comment. That would definitely work if `application` was an environment you defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mdframed`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) provides the means for *wrapping around* other environments. In order to achieve this efficiently, it taps into the `\begin` and `\end` macros that are typically used to represent environments. Hooks of the form `\@beforebegin@<env>@hook` and `\@afterend@<env>@hook` are inserted at the start/end of the environment `<env>`, effectively making an `mdframed`-wrapped environment `myenv` change from

```
\begin{myenv}
  % environment contents
\end{myenv}
```

inside your code to

```
\begin{mdframed}[<options>]
\begin{myenv}
  % environment contents
\end{myenv}
\end{mdframed}
```

As such, just tapping into and changing `myenv` alone is insufficient. One would have to also remove the `mdframed`-inserted environment-wrapping. The following achieves that in a toggle-like fashion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,mdframed,environ}

\mdfdefinestyle{applicationSty}{linewidth=1pt, innermargin =1cm, outermargin =1cm}
\newcounter{applicationCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{applicationCounter}{chapter}

\makeatletter
\let\old@beforebegin@application@hook\@beforebegin@application@hook
\let\old@afterend@application@hook\@afterend@application@hook
\newcommand{\MakeApplicationsTopSecret}{%
  % Make application environment gobbles its contents
  \RenewEnviron{application}{}%
  % Remove mdframed hooks inserted at \begin and \end environment
  \renewcommand{\@beforebegin@application@hook}{}%
  \renewcommand{\@afterend@application@hook}{}%
}
\newcommand{\MakeApplicationsPublic}{%
  \let\application\relax% Clear application macro/environment
  \let\endapplication\relax
  \newmdtheoremenv[style=applicationSty]{application}[applicationCounter]{Application}%
}
\makeatother

\MakeApplicationsPublic% applications are visible/public by default

\begin{document}

This is some text at the start.

\begin{application}
  This is an application.
\end{application}

This is more text in the middle top.

\MakeApplicationsTopSecret
\begin{application}
  This is another application.% This application is removed
\end{application}

This is more text in the middle bottom.

\MakeApplicationsPublic
\begin{application}
  This is another application.
\end{application}

This is more text at the end.

\end{document}
```

`\MakeApplicationsTopSecret` removes both the hooks associated with the `application` environment, as well as gobbles the entire environment contents thanks to [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ). The opposite - restoring the functionality of the `application` environment - is achieved via `\MakeApplicationsPublic`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly solution - the `comment` package doesn't recognize `application` as an environment to be excluded, and I don't seem able to open and close an `application` inside the wrapper, so you have to wrap each `application` by hand. If you're just starting out that may be OK. If you already have a big document it's a nuisance.

Perhaps someone will edit this and improve it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{comment}

\mdfdefinestyle{applicationSty}{linewidth=1pt, innermargin =1cm, outermargin =1cm}
\newcounter{applicationCounter}[chapter]
\numberwithin{applicationCounter}{chapter}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=applicationSty]{application}[applicationCounter]{Aplication}

\newenvironment{applicationwrapper}
{}{}
%{\begin{application}}  % this fails - too bad
%{\end{application}}

\excludecomment{applicationwrapper}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\begin{applicationwrapper}
\begin{application}
    This is an application.
\end{application}
\end{applicationwrapper}

This is more text.

\begin{application}
    This is another application.
\end{application}

This is more text.

\end{document}
```